# C#: Circular enumeration of IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

There is the command hierarchy in my current application.

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}
```

So, some commands are stateful, some are not.

I need to enumerate IEnumerable in the circular way for some command implementation during command execution.

```
public class GetNumberCommand : ICommand
{
    public GetNumberCommand()
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>
            {
                1, 2, 3
            };
    }
    
    public void Execute()
    {
        // Circular iteration here.
        // 1 => 2 => 3 => 1 => 2 => 3 => ...
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // Log current value. (2 for example)
    }
}
```

`Execute` is called from time to time, so it is necessary to store the iteration state.

How to implement that circular enumeration?

I have found two solutions:

1. Using the `IEnumerator<T>` interface.
   It looks like:

   ```
    if (!_enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        _enumerator.Reset();
        _enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
   ```
2. Using the circular `IEnumerable<T>` (`yield` forever the same sequence): [“Implementing A Circular Iterator” - HonestIllusion.Com](https://honestillusion.com/2007/02/28/implementing-a-circular-iterator.html).

Maybe, there are more ways to achieve it.
What would you recommend to use and why?

Comment: For the sake of reusability, I'd implement a Circular Iterator.
Actually I just need one right now, and came here hoping to get some inspiration. But it seems that none of the solutions seems to work.
Well, I had to implement one myself and I'm posting it here as an answer.
Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension method:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> Cyclic<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this)
{
    while (true)
        foreach (var x in @this)
            yield return x;
}
```

In that way:

```cs
public class GetNumberCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<int> _commandState = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Cyclic().GetEnumerator();

    public void Execute()
    {
        _commandState.MoveNext();
        var state = _commandState.Current;
        
        //
        // Do stuff with state
        //
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        var state = _commandState.Current;                
        // Log state value. (2 for example)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your solution is the best (simple and concise) one. It is the same as the solution #2 (see the question) combined with the iteration using the `IEnumerator<T>` interface.

Comment: Just a TODO-note for readers. The appropriate disposal of the `IEnumerator<T>` instance must be implemented.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of dealing with IEnumerator interface,

```
foreach (var x in GetSomething())
{
     if (someCondition) break;
}



public IEnumerable<int> GetSomething()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    int index=0;

    while (true)
        yield return list[index++ % list.Count];
}
```

Comment: I think you will get overflow on index very soon if do like that

Comment: In my case, `Execute` is called from time to time, so it is necessary to store the iteration state.

Comment: see my solution in the end. you can store index in the collection and pass it to iterator

Comment: Okay, I see the point. Out of curiosity, how about `IEnumerable<T>` (not `List<T>`)?

Comment: I used List only for example, you can use whatever you want :) My example is very ugly and not for production code. It was just being used to show the idea.

Comment: @Serge , *"Execute is called from time to time, so it is necessary to store the iteration state."* Is it so hard to move `int index=0;` out of `GetSomething` ?

Comment: @EugenePetrov *"I think you will get overflow on index very soon if do like that."* , Yes if you want to iterate  `1 => 2 => 3 => 1 => 2 ....` loop more than 2 billions times it may overflow. thanks to god that `long` exists ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one I just implemented as an extension.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DroopyExtensions
{
    public static class CircularEnumaratorExtensionMethod
    {

        public static IEnumerator<T> GetCircularEnumerator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> t) 
        {
            return new CircularEnumarator<T>(t.GetEnumerator());
        }

        private class CircularEnumarator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
        {
            private readonly IEnumerator _wrapedEnumerator;

            public CircularEnumarator(IEnumerator wrapedEnumerator)
            {
                this._wrapedEnumerator = wrapedEnumerator;
            }

            public object Current => _wrapedEnumerator.Current;

            T IEnumerator<T>.Current =>  (T)Current;

            public void Dispose()
            {

            }

            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                if (!_wrapedEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    _wrapedEnumerator.Reset();
                    return _wrapedEnumerator.MoveNext();
                }
                return true;
            }

            public void Reset()
            {
                _wrapedEnumerator.Reset();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

To use it, all you have to do is

```
using DroopyExtensions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<string>() {"One", "Two", "Tree"};
        var dataEnumerator = data.GetCircularEnumerator();
        while(dataEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataEnumerator.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should swap the implementation of `IEnumerator.Current` and `CircularEnumarator<T>.Current`, because there is no need to unboxing.(`_wrapedEnumerator` should be `IEnumerator<T>` not `IEnumerator`)

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!stop)
{
   foreach (var i in numbers)
   {
     // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: In my case, `Execute` is called from time to time, so it is necessary to store the iteration state.

Answer (score -1):

I think, the most comfortable way wil be to implement custom collection with custom enumerator and encapsulate circular logic in it.

```
class Collection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
  bool circle;

  List<T> collection = new List<T>();

  public IEnumerable<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
  {
     if(circle) return new CustomEnumerator<T>(this);
     return circle.GetEnumerator();
  }
}

class CustomEnumerator : Enumerator<T> {}
```

something like this...

Answer (score -1):

You can write a circular enumerable without yield returns.

```
  public class CircularEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
  {
    public CircularEnumerable (IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
      InfiniteLoop = sequence.Concat (this);
    }

    private readonly IEnumerable<T> InfiniteLoop;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator ()
    {
      return InfiniteLoop.GetEnumerator ();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator ()
    {
      return InfiniteLoop.GetEnumerator ();
    }
  }

public class GetNumberCommand : ICommand
{
    public GetNumberCommand()
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>
            {
                1, 2, 3
            };
        infiniteLoopOnNumbers = new CircularEnumerable<int>(numbers).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<int> infiniteLoopOnNumbers; 

    public void Execute()
    {
        infiniteLoopOnNumbers.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        int value = infiniteLoopOnNumbers.Current;
    }
}
```